# WebdriverIO .toHaveText() gives false positive result

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver-io

I wanted to assert element's text. After reading https://webdriver.io/ documentation I thought using `expect (await myPage.myElement).toHaveText('wrong text')` would make my test fail, but it does not.
Why doesn't the test fail?

1. Expected it to fail, but it passes

```
console.log(await myPage.myElement.getText()); // prints out 'actual text'
expect (await myPage.myElement).toHaveText('wrong text')
```

2. Then tried with

```
console.log(await myPage.myElement.getText()); // prints out 'actual text'
expect (await myPage.myElement.getText()).toContain('wrong text')
```

and this time it fails, as I expected. But not sure if this is the best practice

3. I also tried with

```
console.log(await myPage.myElement.getText()); // prints out 'actual text'
expect (await myPage.myElement).toHaveTextContaining('wrong text')
```

but this time VSC says it's deprecated, although it's included on documentation page